# fscanf reads string but when I copy string to array it modifies the whole array

Tags: c

I have this code. This is the file content

```
nasa.txt
news1.txt
file11.txt
mixed.txt
planets.txt
file21.txt
info31.txt
```

This is the code

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(collectionFilename, "r");

    char url[MAX_WORD + 1];
    char *urls[MAX_WORD + 1];

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", url) == 1){
        urls[index++] = url;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        printf("%s\n", urls[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

I want the code to read in the file names and store them into my urls array. However my `printf` statement at the end prints info31.txt 7 times and I'm a bit confused as to why this happens.

Thank you!

Comment: "but when I copy string to array" is a falsify.  `urls[index++] = url;` copies a pointer, not a _string_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica How do I copy the string then?

Comment: To copy a string, research `strcpy()`.

Comment: I am doing that but now I get this 

==10731== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10731==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4844000
==10731==    at 0x4838DC8: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:512)
==10731==    by 0x109898: generateInvertedIndex (invertedIndex.c:101)
==10731==    by 0x1092B4: test1 (testInvertedIndex.c:36)
==10731==    by 0x109244: main (testInvertedIndex.c:23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code there are two steps in the loop

1. `fscanf(fp, "%s", url)` will read string and write the string to `url`
2. `urls[index++] = url;` will assign `urls[index]` to **point to** `url` and increase `index` by one

The key point is that in step 2, you just repeat the same thing to every elements in `urls` -- pointing them to `url`, which is why you get the same URL from `urls`. You never copy the characters from `url` to somewhere else and `fscanf` just keep using the same buffer for input in every iteration.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense. So how would I get it to copy the contents then? Is this where I would use strcpy instead?

Comment: `strcpy` can be used, but you also need to prepare buffer for that too. Another different problem but a critical one with your code is buffer overflow because `url` might be too small to hold the string. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c for more information about that.

Comment: Why do I need to prepare a buffer for strcpy? How would I go about it?